# Display multiple custom post type lists on homepage - multiple loops

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I've got to display 6 boxes on the homepage of a site I'm working on and struggling with the code. I've managed to get this far:

```
<?php 
$term = get_term( hotelCategoryID, 'accommodation-category' );
$output = '<div class="box"> ';
if (function_exists('get_terms_meta'))
{
     $category_hotel = get_terms_meta(hotelCategoryID, 'image_taxonomy',true);

}
if($category_hotel ) : 
$output .= '<img src="'.$category_hotel.'" width="300" alt="'.$term->name.'" />';
endif;
$output .= '<div class="textbox"> 
                <em class="corner">corner</em>
                <h2>'.$term->name.'</h2>'.
                $term->description.'
            </div>';?>
<?php 
 $args = array('post_type' => 'accommodation','tax_query' => array( array('taxonomy' => 'accommodation-category','field' => 'id','terms' => hotelCategoryID)));
query_posts($args);?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : $count_post = 0;
    $output .= '<div class="list-area"><ul>';
   while (have_posts()) : the_post();
 if($count_post==5) $output .='</ul><ul class="list">';
 $count_post++;
 $output .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
 endwhile;
 $output .= '</ul>
    <div class="opener-holder">
        <a class="opener" href="#"><span>+&nbsp;&nbsp; MORE '.$term->name.'</span><em>-&nbsp;&nbsp; LESS '.$term->name.'</em></a> 
    </div>
</div>';
endif; wp_reset_query();
$output .= '</div>';?>
```

But when I copy the code and modify it to get the information from another custom post type it just displays one block on the homepage, I assume it's an issue with the loop in this code. I've tried various other codes but this is the one that I need as it has "5" highlighted posts, and then the rest aren't.

Could someone give me an idea on how to edit the loop so I can display 6 of these on one page please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without a little more detail or seeing the entire page's code, but I'm going to wage that your issue is `$output = '<div class="box"> ';`. If you're repeating that line before `echo` or `print`ing `$output`, then you're losing the value of `$output`. If that's the issue, change this line to `$output .= '<div class="box"> ';` and at the very top of the page, add `$output = '';`